# Which current is largest?

Tags: bjt

[image]

I have this circuit and the question is what is the relationship between the 3 currents(meaning if I1 is  > < or = to the I2 and so on). The way i see it I2 and I3 are zero since they are npn bjts and in order for a npn bjt to conduct must be Vc >> Ve.In Q3 Vc = Ve (they are wired this way) and in the Q2 Vc = 0 and Ve = 0.Also Ic1 = Ib1 which makes me think that the Q1 doesnt conduct as well ( if it was it was in active mode Ic = β Ib and if it was in saturation Ib >= Ic/β and b is always rather larger than 1) so all 3 must be 0 is this correct?

Comment: *"I2 and I3 are zero"* Nope! Think again. What is between base and emitter.

Comment: Is the collector on T2 just randomly going off into space? Btw, to avoid confusion, don't label a transistor as T and call it Q lol :)

Comment: Unfortunately the question has no answer. The 2V supply is much greater (one would assume) than any of the Base-Emitter junctions Vf and a very large current would flow destroying the junctions. You could perhaps say that all three currents =0 since the devices are all blown up.

Comment: Why won't you [just simulate it](http://tinyurl.com/y9qa9tgx)?

Comment: Between the base and the emitter its as if we have a diode. As for the collector in the T2 i guess its not connected anywhere it was given to me like that. As for the 2V supply that  is big but i don't think they care about the blowing up.But out of curiosity how much would someone put before blowing up if you know?

Comment: I don't want to simulate it cause i want to learn the reasoning behind it not to get a result only.

Comment: In a situation like this where the power supply specification isn't given we would have to assume that an infinite (or very large) current was available at 2 V.

Comment: Closing as unclear since it makes no sense to force 2 V across the B-E junction of a (presumably silicon) transistor.  That would be out of spec, so the rest of the question can't be answered since it relies on a impossible situation.

Comment: @Transistor doesn't matter because we don't have a part number for the transistors and wouldn't be able to determine current anyway

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I1 will be the highest.  I3 will be next, as both the BE and BC junctions are conducting from V+ to GND.  I2 is the lowest, as only the BE junction is conducting.

Once powered on, if the supply is ideal (2V 0ohm infinite current), this means T1 (fed by I1, the highest current, and thus dissipating the highest power) will be the first to suffer thermal overload.  It might fail short or fail open, but if it fails short the resulting current should evaporate the wires, traces, or leadframe leading to it resulting in an open.  T3 will be the next to go (I3 is second highest) followed by T2.

If the 2V source has a reasonable source impedance (compared to the power handling capabilities of the transistors), T1 will pull the 2V rail down to about 0.65 and all those disasters will be averted.  Note that T1's BE junction is in its linear range, since Ice is limiting Vb, so the BE (and CE) junctions of T2 and T3 won't reach saturation and these currents will be even smaller in proportion.  Some base resistors (base/collector in the case of T1) might be recommended before you prototype it.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least the first two conduct different current

I1 will be largest, its a current source, and you have both the base *and the collector* current.

Ie = Ib+Ic

I2 and I3 will be next with only base current, the base current still conducts even thought there is no collector current. I suspect that I3 will be lower than I2 but I don't have a good reason for this.

Comment: Vce must be around 0.7V, which means very low current. Otherwise Vce drops and cuts the base current as well